# Opening programs from their directories

Tags: linux, bash, debian, terminal

I am having some troubles while opening files through terminal. For example when I go to PhpStorm directory `cd /home/downloads/phpstorm/` and I'm entering `phpstorm.sh` it is not opening saying there is no such a command or directory. On the other hand, when i just take my mouse, and drag and drop the phpstorm.sh icon to the terminal and press enter, it opens without any problems. As you can probably see I am a really fresh guy with linuxes but its really confusing me. I tried adding it to the $PATH but it also doesnt help, maybe I am doing something wrong or I just dont understand its logic. Any help please?

Comment: How exactly are you entering the command to run the program?  For most programs that aren't in /usr/bin (or your distro's equivalent), you have to type `./` first.  In this example, it would be `./phpstorm.sh`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean I should be installing everything in /bin directory?

Comment: You're welcome.

Just in case, probably not.  If that program requires files in the directory that it currently occupies, then moving it to /usr/bin would break the program.

Comment: In Linux, personal additions to commands which may be installed as stand-alones (*i.e.*, they do not require other files in order to work) are best installed in **/usr/local/bin**; then make sure your *$PATH* variable includes this directory.